# Liftover dog canFam3 to human hg19

Tags: bioinformatics

Hi my question is relatively simple. I've converted dog coordinates to human using UCSC LiftOver. These are 200bp intergenic regions that are differentially methylated from normal dogs to cancer dogs.

I've converted these to human coordinates and found that a lot of them overlap with differentially methylated regions we found in the human model. Is this okay to do?

What stringencies should I check or modify, the min ratio of bases needed to overlap?

Lastly, is this program taking the 200bp dog sequence and saying that at least 10% of the sequence has to align with a region within the human genome?

I haven't seen a sufficient answer online yet.

Comment: This question may be a better fit for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/